Error in adding an image to Azure Devops with API POST
I'm trying to add an image in a field in my Azure Devops, but I keep getting this error:

I'm using this code to store it into the text box:
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Description",
    "from": null,
    "value": "<div><img src=%22https%3A//dev.azure.com/myorg/mytoken/_apis/wit/attachments/8c339e7d-a25e-4980-93bc-87fa2eaba43e?fileName=dssdfsdfsdf.png%22><br></div>"
}

When I click in that "blank" image, I get a page with this information:
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).",
    "typeName": "System.Web.HttpException, System.Web",
    "typeKey": "HttpException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}

The API request that I'm doing is:
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version=7.1-preview.3

It does give me a success response, and returns the link that I entered in the <img src= element.
But then the image isn't being shown.
I tried changing the ":" in the img source to an %3A but it doesn't work either.

The rest api is used to add attachment only, cannot image add to work item description field.
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version=7.1-preview.3

With above rest api, you can get the attached image url:
$organization = "ORG"
$project = "PROJECT"
$fileName = "testimage.png"
$personalAccessToken = "YourPAT"
$filePath = "C:\Users\wade\Downloads\testimage.png"   # image file path

$uploadUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=$fileName&api-version=7.1-preview.3"

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$personalAccessToken"))
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadUrl -Method Post -Headers $headers -InFile $filePath -ContentType 'application/octet-stream'

$imageUrl = $response.url

Write-Host The imageurl is: $imageUrl


With the image url, you can use rest api Work Items - Update to add image to the work item description field. Change the work item id to yours.
$organization = "ORG"
$project = "Project"
$personalAccessToken = "YourPAT"

$workItemId = "498"        # change to use your work item id
$updateUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/$workItemId"+ "?api-version=7.1-preview.3"

$imageUrl= "your image url get from above rest api"

$description = "<div>add testimage in description<img src='$imageUrl' 'alt=testimage.png'></div>"


$body = @(
    @{
        op = "add"
        path = "/fields/System.Description"
        value = $description
    }
)


$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$personalAccessToken"))
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateUrl -Method Patch -Headers $headers -Body (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body) -ContentType 'application/json-patch+json'

Image added to the description:

The whole script is below:
$organization = "ORG"
$project = "Project"
$fileName = "testimage.png"
$personalAccessToken = "YourPAT"
$filePath = "C:\Users\wade\Downloads\testimage.png"


$workItemId = "498"

$uploadUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=$fileName&api-version=7.1-preview.3"


$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$personalAccessToken"))
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadUrl -Method Post -Headers $headers -InFile $filePath -ContentType 'application/octet-stream'

$imageUrl = $response.url

Write-Host The imageurl is: $imageUrl

$description = "<div>add testimage in description<img src='$imageUrl' 'alt=testimage.png'></div>"

$body = @(
    @{
        op = "add"
        path = "/fields/System.Description"
        value = $description
    }
)

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateUrl -Method Patch -Headers $headers -Body (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body) -ContentType 'application/json-patch+json'

You can refer to below similar ticket for your reference:
How to add inline image in Azure Devops work item description
pass a valid patch document to update work item using Powershell
Edit:
If your source image is external online, you need to store it firstly, change the attachment code as below:
$organization = "orgname"
$project = "projectname"
$fileName = "testimage.png"
$personalAccessToken = "PAT"

# Define the URL of the image and the path where you want to save it
$imageUrl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/movidesk-files/D584934F217A52B0230B0870091B7EFA"
$filePath = "C:\Users\wade\Downloads\testimage.png"

# Download the image
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $imageUrl -OutFile $filePath


$uploadUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=$fileName&api-version=7.1-preview.3"


$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$personalAccessToken"))
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadUrl -Method Post -Headers $headers -InFile $filePath -ContentType 'application/octet-stream'

$imageUrl = $response.url

Write-Host The imageurl is: $imageUrl


The thing is that i wanted to make it in a way that i dont need to download the image.
I have the image coming from the API as this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/movidesk-files/D584934F217A52B0230B0870091B7EFA
Then i try to put it on the system.description and the error i said above pops up.
What am i missing?

You need two steps with two rest api to add screenshot to description field.  You mixed up the api, your request body is used for work item -update rest api not attachment rest api.  In addition, for both rest api, they don't accept external online image link. You need to download the image and upload as attachment firstly.

You can use Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $imageUrl -OutFile $filePath to download the image, and then add it to the attachement. i edit withe answer with sample code.
